# I'm trying to check the filesystem at boot, but I'm encountering an error that prevents fsck from completing

Tags: debian, fsck

While attempting to resolve issues related to a seemingly full disk, I'm trying to check the filesystem on the root of my ASUS Tinkerboard 2S (Debian 10).

I encountered the following errors in the logs:

```
systemd-sysctl[195]: Couldn't write 'force' to 'fsck/mode', ignoring: No such file or directory
systemd-sysctl[195]: Couldn't write 'yes' to 'fsck/repair', ignoring: No such file or directory
```

Further confirmation of this comes from checking the date of the last check with `tune2fs -l /dev/mmcblk2p9 | grep 'checked\|Maximum\|Mount'` when it shows a date from last year:

```
Mount count:              172
Maximum mount count:      1
Last checked:             Tue May  3 13:10:09 2022
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: This is probably a problem linked to `systemd` and its logging. Try `tune2fs -C 2 -c 1 /dev/mmcblk2p9` reboot and after reboot set the count back from 1 to 172. Or boot from a live distro and do the `fsck` from that distro.

Answer (score 2):

`systemd-sysctl`'s job is to run early in the boot process, read the configuration files in `/etc/sysctl.d` and write any settings found in there to the kernel's virtual files located under `/proc/sys`.

But that looks like there are settings like `fsck.mode=force` and `fsck.repair=yes` in some file within `/etc/sysctl.d/`. Those would map to virtual files `/proc/sys/fsck/mode` and `/proc/sys/fsck/repair`, respectively... except that filesystem checking tools won't usually have in-kernel components (and definitely not with an `ext4` filesystem!), so it would seem that those settings are in a wrong place. Whether this is because of an operator error or filesystem corruption, I cannot say at the moment.

Instead, those settings would make sense as *kernel boot parameters*. On an x86 system, those parameters could be added added to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` or `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` variable of `/etc/default/grub`. But since Tinkerboard 2S is an ARM device, it does not use GRUB, but some other bootloader... maybe `u-boot`? (I could not find clear example of a Tinkerboard 2S boot process with quick Googling.)

If the bootloader is `u-boot`, then this document might more or less match what you're seeing at the beginning of the boot process:

https://wiki.debian.org/U-boot/#U-boot_prompt.2C_custom_kernel_arguments

In short: when you see a `Hit any key to stop autoboot:` prompt with a 3-second countdown, you should have a serial console connected and press any key on it to gain access to a u-boot prompt: `=>`.

To trigger a one-time filesystem check, you would then enter the following commands:

```
setenv bootargs ${bootargs} fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes
boot
```

The important thing is to not outright *replace* the existing `bootargs` value, but to *add to it*.

Using the command `saveenv` after the `setenv` command line would make the options persistent (instead of one-boot-only), but you should first try without `saveenv`, just in case there are further problems with the filesystem check.

Comment: Wow. This will take me some time to work through. Thanks for all the research. I also worked out the Tinkerboard 2S does not use GRUB so you seem to be on the right path :) I'll report back here with progress

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @telcoM

In the end I found an alternative approach, which only works on the Tinkerboard 2S, because, in addition to the eMMC storage (where my root is), the device also has a Micro SD slot. When the Micro SD slot is used, the boot prefers this to the eMMC

So I found at home a 128GB Micro SD and flashed the Debian 10 provided by ASUS. After some basic set-up I was able to unmount the partition on the old root and run `fsck`

Comment: That's a perfectly valid approach too, and also you now have a proven way to boot the system from an external media if it ever becomes necessary because of some other issue. Good job!

Comment: Thanks @telcoM You gave well-researched help that pushed me in the right direction :)